# tmux session killed when disconnecting from ssh

Tags: tmux, sshd

**Summary**: I'm trying to figure out why my tmux session dies when I disconnect from ssh

**Details**:

I have tmux installed on an Arch Linux system.  When I start a tmux session I can detach from it and then attach again while the ssh session is active.  But if I end my ssh session then the tmux session gets killed.

I know this is not the normal behavior because I have other system where the tmux session continues running even if the ssh session is ended and I can attach to the tmux session after establishing a new ssh connection.  The system that has a problem and the one that works correctly have very similar configurations so I'm not sure what to check.

I'm running tmux version 1.9a.  The system that has a problem (that I have root access for) has a Linux kernel version of 3.17.4-1 and the system that works correct has kernel version 3.16.4-1-ARCH (I don't have root on that system).  I doubt that the kernel version is the source of the problem though, that's just one difference I noticed.

I thought I'd ask to see if anyone has seen a similar problem and knows of a possible solution.

The precise steps that lead to the problem are:

1. ssh to machine
2. run `tmux` to start tmux
3. `ctrl-B D` to detach (at this point I could reattach with `tmux attach`
4. close ssh session (at this point the tmux session is killed, I've been able to observe this when I'm logged in as root in a different terminal)
5. reconnect with ssh and run `tmux attach` and I get the message `no sessions` and running `tmux ls` returns `failed to connect to server: Connection refused`.  This makes sense because the serve is not running.  What doesn't make sense to me is why it gets killed in step 4 when I disconnect from the ssh session.

**strace data:**

In response to one of the comments I used strace to see what systems calls the tmux server process makes.  It looks like when I exit my ssh session (by typing `exit` or with `ctrl-d`) that the tmux process is being killed.  Here's a snippet of the final part of the strace output.

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 3, 424) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
--- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1, si_uid=0} ---
sendto(3, "\17", 1, 0, NULL, 0)         = 1
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

I compared this with a different system where tmux works properly and on that system the tmux process continues running even after I exit.  So the root cause appears to be that the tmux process is being terminated when I close the ssh session.  I'll need to spend some time troubleshooting this to figure out why, but I thought I would update my question since the strace suggestion was useful.

Comment: to be sure, please describe step by step : I assume you ssh, start a tmux session, detach from the session, and close the  shh : when you ssh again, you don t have any way to re join the tmix session? ie, the session is no longer running?

Comment: @OlivierDulac yes your assumption is correct.  I've also edited my question to include these details.

Comment: how do you close the ssh session? and you could attach a strace to the pid of tmux and another to the pid of the sshd, to see if it receives something when you close the ssh connection (very verbose, redirect to a file)

Comment: @OlivierDulac thanks for the suggestion.  I've updated the question with info from strace.  It looks like the tmux server process is getting killed when I end the ssh session.  I don't think this is supposed to happen, so I need to figure out why it is happening.

Comment: Start tmux with verbose logging enabled and see if anything is printed to the log when you disconnect. Also, what is the TERM on the remote machine in and out of tmux?

Comment: Anything exotic in .tmux.conf? A crazy idea, but does screen do the same, with "autodetach on" in your .screenrc? That would imply that some external watcher is sending the kill signal.

~$ tmux show-options -g | grep tach
destroy-unattached off
detach-on-destroy on

Comment: @jasonwryan thanks for the suggestion.  I didn't see anything noteworthy when running with verbose logging. The TERM is xterm out of tmux and screen-256color in tmux.

Comment: @IanMcGowan there's nothing exotic in the .tmux.conf file.  I don't have screen installed right now, but I'll try that later.  But I am starting to suspect that systemd is sending a signal to the tmux process.  So I don't know if it's a tmux problem or some other configuration in my system.  I've also posted to the Arch Linux forum asking about this (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1482809).  It's not a high priority for me, but it would be nice to fix so I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Is there anything curious in your `~/.bash_logout` (or shell equivalent), or a `trap` in your `~/.bashrc` that would propagate a hangup signal into the equivalent of `pkill -9 -P $$` ? Consider tracing the `bash` parent of the `tmux` process and see if it is sending a `SIGKILL` to `tmux`.

Comment: @Gabriel Before I award the bounty to mirabilos, did his answer solve your issue?

Comment: @eyoung100 I'm traveling right now so I was planning to look at the answers/comments once I got back.  I hadn't even noticed there was a bounty for the question.  I don't want to try to change my ssh settings till I get back because I don't have any other way to access the system remotely in case there's a problem.  The answer sounds like it will fix the problem, but I won't be able to check till Jan 2.

Comment: See also: [*tmux killed when connection abruptly closed by remote host, but survives when logging out manually*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323237/15654)

Comment: Also related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490267/prevent-logoff-from-killing-tmux-session

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Theory

Some init systems including systemd provide a feature to kill all processes belonging to the service. The service typically starts a single process which that creates more processes by forking and those processes can do that as well. All such processes are typically considered part of the service. In systemd this is done using *cgroups*.

In systemd, all processes belonging to a service are killed when the service is stopped by default. The SSH server is obviously part of the service. When you connect to the server, SSH server typically forks and the new process handles your SSH session. By forking from the SSH session process or its children, other server side processes are started, including your *screen* or *tmux*.

### Killmode and socket activation

The default behavior can be changed using the `KillMode` directive. The upstream project doesn't AFAIK include any `.service` files and so those vary by distribution. There are typically two ways to enable SSH on your system. One is the classic `ssh.service` that maintains a long running SSH daemon listening on the network. The other is via socket activation handled by the `ssh.socket` that in turn starts `sshd@.service` which only runs for a single SSH session.

### Solutions

If your processes get killed at the end of the session, it is possible that you are using socket activation and it gets killed by systemd when it notices that the SSH session process exited. In that case there are two solutions. One is to avoid using socket activation by using `ssh.service` instead of `ssh.socket`. The other is to set `KillMode=process` in the `Service` section of `ssh@.service`.

The `KillMode=process` setting may also be useful with the classic `ssh.service`, as it avoids killing the SSH session process or the *screen* or *tmux* processes when the server gets stopped or restarted.

### Future notes

This answer apparently gained a level of popularity. While it worked for the OP it might happen that it doesn't work for someone in the future due to *systemd-logind*  development or configuration. Please check documentation on logind sessions if you experience behavior different from the description in this answer.

Comment: Any specific feedback from the downvoter or just trolling?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Switching to sshd.service fixed the problem.

Comment: I experience this problem on a system using `init` rather than `systemd`.  But it's slightly different anyway, see [my question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323237/15654).

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem with tmux and screen on Ubuntu 16.04 (kde neon). When the ssh session was disconnected screen / tmux was terminated.

long story short, systemd changed their default setting to killuserprocess=yes so after leaving a ssh session every process created by it will be terminated.

Easy fix (after hours of trying) run screen/tmux using this command

For screen

`systemd-run --scope --user screen`

for Tmux

`systemd-run --scope --user tmux`

You can create an alias to make it easier

`alias tmux= "systemd-run --scope --user tmux"`

Comment: `-bash: systemd-run: command not found` on `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)`.

Comment: Does this work when I have not got root?

Comment: I noticed the undesired tmux/screen killing behavior does not happen on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, only 16.04.

Comment: Note that this only works when you have any other login session active, as soon as you logout the last session, all processes started in a separate scope like this will still be killed. This can be prevented by enabling lingering (run `loginctl enable-linger`, only needs to be done once). See  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html#Examples (example 5) for more details.

Comment: Still fails for me. `sudo loginctl enable-linger`, then `systemd-run --scope --user tmux` gives  
`Job for run-r835c0bf5a0014105adf82bf21dd95434.scope failed.`  
`journalctl -xe` gives  
`run-r835c0bf5a0014105adf82bf21dd95434.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: Permission denied`  
`run-r835c0bf5a0014105adf82bf21dd95434.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.`

Comment: [Perhaps there is a solution for this problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=227953) but I cannot test currently.  The machine is ~100km away and 802.1x is a bit fragile there, such that the machine sometimes does not get back into the network without manual intervention (this is: unplug+replug network cable.  AFAICS it's a Cisco bug introduced to support some bad BIOS variants found on Windows hardware when PXE boot is required as well.  A bit esoteric, but harmful combination).

Comment: Thank. I have the same problem that `screen` and `tmux` is terminated after ssh session end in Ubuntu 20.04. Adding the alias into `.bashrc` solve it.

Answer (score 5):

Do you use systemd with socket activation for SSH?

If so, there’s [a known issue with that](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.systemd.devel/2379/focus=2391). According to the systemd proponents, this is actually a feature – systemd kills all processes spawned by a session when the session terminates. (I can see that being useful, but in the GNU `screen`, or `tmux`, case, you definitely **don’t** want that ☺ nor in most other cases where users may run background processes, of course.)

If so, [try switching from `sshd.socket` to `sshd.service`](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.systemd.devel/2379/focus=2381).

Comment: I would say you generally don't want to use that feature for SSH logins if your users are allowed to run processes that are running after logging out. That's not specific to screen or tmux but rather to SSH (with any background processes on the server side).

Comment: @PavelŠimerda yes, I thought that implicit, but edited the post to make it more explicit now.

Comment: The links are down, answer would be more useful if it had the information from the links.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution to this, which doesn't require moving from `sshd.socket` to `sshd.service`, is to start `tmux` server as a systemd service [0]. This way, the `tmux` server is already running when you SSH into the server, instead of spawned by the `tmux` command in SSH, thus won't be killed.

[0] https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Autostart_with_systemd

Comment: Does this work when I have not got root?

Comment: Yeah, that's a valid solution. But you still want to solve the case with restarting SSH service over SSH session. :)

Comment: Guys, in case you use OpenRC, I made a [tmux initscript](https://gitlab.com/Megver83/init-scripts/tree/master/tmux) that does the same as the service file mentioned in the ArchWiki

Answer (score 2):

I found the following to work from `https://pastebin.com/2cifCXGk` (answer copied from this reference).

Create the file /etc/systemd/system/tmux@.service with the contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start tmux in detached session
Documentation=man:tmux(1)

[Service]
Type=forking
User=%I
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s %u -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t %u

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then enable the service for each user:

```
sudo systemctl enable tmux@${USER}.service
sudo systemctl start tmux@${USER}.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Alternatively, you can place this file within your systemd/User directory (without `User=%I`), for example `~/.config/systemd/user/tmux.service`.
This way the tmux service will start when you log in, unless you also enable automatic start-up of systemd user instances.

Comment: Following the discussion in the bug report they reverted the default to not kill background processes in 2016.

Comment: If you have - in username try using %i instead of %I