# How can I spawn a TTY text virtual console?

Tags: kali-linux, console, tty

Due to (what I think is) some sort of bug on the Linux version (Kali v2.0) of my remote computer, my **TTY text consoles do not start** until I locally sit on the machine and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd>.

I use to remotely login via **SSH** into that computer, and then I access the TTY n by using [ConSpy](https://sourceforge.net/p/conspy/), so, for example:

```
# conspy 6
```

sends my SSH client (Putty in my case) to TTY6.

But, as long as TTY consoles have not started, I only get a **blank screen** with the cursor blinking.
So I firstly send:

```
# agetty 38400 tty6 &
```

And then the TTY6 starts running, so this time I can login and interact, but I get this strange message:

```
Kali GNU/Linux 2.0 kali tty6
kali login: luis
Password:
Linux kali 4.0.0-kali1-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) i686

The programs included with the Kali GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Kali GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
-bash: cannot set terminal process group (3662): Inappropriate ioctl for device
-bash: no job control in this shell
```

Is the `agetty` command the proper method to **spawn a TTY** text virtual console?

Comment: is there any reason you need to attach to a TTY when ssh already gives you a shell every bit as good?  are you re-inventing GNU `screen` or `tmux`?

Comment: BTW, i suspect your problem is because Kali 2.0 is based on Debian jessie, which has switched to `systemd`.  Systemd starts gettys on demand.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56531/how-to-get-fewer-ttys-with-systemd

Comment: @cas : Just a example: if you (remotely) order `cp HugeFile /Destination/Path` via SSH, there is a risk for connection (internet) hangups to break (mess) the full process. If you (remotely) order `cp` on (remote) TTY there is no such risk.

Comment: Read about `nohup`, `screen`, `tmux` and maybe `batch` and `at`...

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: as i thought, you're (partially) reinventing `screen` etc.  they all solve that problem (and a lot more)

Comment: @casm indeed, `screen` is another way of doing the same remote tasks I do on TTYs. Having alternatives is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

### This is by design.

> Due to (what I think is) some sort of bug on the Linux version (Kali v2.0) of my remote computer, my TTY text consoles do not start until I locally sit on the machine and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F*n*</kbd>.

This is not a bug.  This is systemd Linux working as designed.  TTY login services for kernel virtual terminals are started on demand by `logind`, as they are switched into the foreground.  If you are accessing the the machine remotely and using ConSpy, you are of course *not* switching kernel virtual terminals into the foreground.

> Is the `agetty` command the proper method to spawn a TTY text virtual console?

Yes, and no.  Yes, it's the way to spawn a *getty/login service*.  No, it doesn't spawn the virtual terminal itself.  No, you don't run it directly.

As stated, `logind` does this.  There's a systemd service, named `autovt@ttyN.service`, for each virtual terminal.  That is what runs `agetty`.  One starts that service manually, or lets `logind` start it upon demand.

### The problems of `screen` and `tmux` with systemd.

Of course, as noted you are using the kernel's virtual terminal subsystem and ConSpy as the server and client parts of a system like `screen` or `tmux`.  You could switch to using `screen` or `tmux`.

The problem with `screen` and `tmux` is that they don't interoperate well with systemd.  This is a known systemd problem, and is also by design.  If you start the server part of `screen` or `tmux` from within a login session that is managed directly as a service by systemd (as `autovt@ttyN.service` services are, and as indeed `sshd@connection.service` services are when running SSH in `Accept=yes` mode) then systemd *kills the server when you log out*, because by design it kills all still-left-around processes within a service when that service terminates, and logging out of such login session services counts as termination.

The world has a choice of workarounds for this design conflict, include such things as changing the kill mode of `sshd@.service`.  By far the best approach is to make the `screen` or `tmux` server *itself* into a managed service.  You thus don't start `screen` or `tmux` by logging in and running it interactively.  You start it by having it as a fully-fledged service that is started and stopped via systemd.

At which point, all of the stuff in `screen` and `tmux` to fork off a server process in the background is at best overengineered, as the background server part is *all* that a systemd-managed `screen` or `tmux` service needs to do, and it doesn't need to "dæmonize" its server.  (Ironically, the problem that `screen` and `tmux` have with systemd is *yet another* example of why it is actually impossible to safely, securely, and reliably "dæmonize" from an interactive login session.)

### Alternatives

Since you mention alternatives, here is another:  nosh has a *user-space* virtual terminal system.  You could run the nosh service manager under systemd, and some of the nosh `ttylogin@vcN-tty` and `terminal-emulator@vcN`services under it, talking to the emulated terminals from SSH login sessions with `console-ncurses-realizer`.  (If you adjusted ConSpy to not hardwire device names as it currently does, you could even view the emulated terminals with ConSpy, since there's a vcsa-compatible display buffer available.)  `console-terminal-emulator` doesn't "dæmonize" and does just the one job, of emulating a terminal and sitting between the master side of a pseudo-terminal and the emulated display and input.

There are a couple of incidental benefits of this:  It's not constrained by kernel-space design constraints, and so is a more complete DEC VT emulation than the emulator programs built into kernels.  Terminals can be resized with the ordinary DEC control sequences, to arbitrary sizes.  Terminals auto-reset, for security, *immediately on log-off* rather than on next invocation of log-on.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132
- Lennart Poettering (2011-05-19). [*[bug?] screen not working correctly under systemd*](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.systemd.devel/2379/focus=2391).  systemd-devel.
- ["Autostart with systemd"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Autostart_with_systemd). *tmux*.  Arch Wiki.
- Paul Eggleton (2014-11-06).  [*openssh: avoid screen sessions being killed on disconnect with systemd*](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/?h=daisy&id=6c576a4ac85307a5c851bee91a567cae3ea5a43b).  Yocto Project.
- [tmux session killed when disconnecting from ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171503/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). ["Running nosh service management under systemd"](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/debian-binary-packages.html#systemd).  *Debian binary packages*.  nosh.  JdeBP's Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*The timorous admin's installation how-to*](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/timorous-admin-installation-how-to.html)  nosh.  JdeBP's Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). ["user-space virtual terminals"](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/user-virtual-terminals.html).  *nosh Guide*.  1.20.  nosh.  JdeBP's Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*A quick look at user-space virtual terminals*](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/user-vt-screenshots.html)  nosh.  JdeBP's Softwares.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/674147/43344
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). ["Inheritance and the daemonization fallacy"](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/bsd-service-command.html#Inheritance). *No more problems with the 'service' command*.  nosh.  JdeBP's Softwares.