# Tmux sessions get killed on ssh logout

Tags: systemd, tmux, sshd

I am using tmux on a remote machine that I access over ssh. For some reason, the tmux sessions do not persist between consecutive ssh login sessions. I do not have this issue while logging into this other remote machine that I have access to. This is essentially the same issue as described in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171503/tmux-session-killed-when-disconnecting-from-ssh).

However, the machine that I use already uses `ssh.service` rather than `ssh.socket`, so the accepted answer does not work for me.

Exact steps taken:

1. Login to the machine via ssh
2. Start a tmux session, do some work.
3. Detach session, and possibly attach again (this works).
4. Log out with Ctrl+D.
5. Login again and try tmux a or tmux ls (doesn't work).

Comment: Also, did you try the `KillMode=process` option, listed in the answer you linked to? If that works, then this is actually a duplicate.

Comment: @ArturMeinild `KillMode=process` is what I have by  default in the `Service` section of `sshd.service`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution to my problem.

The reason for the killing of the tmux sessions was the default setting of `KillUserProcesses=yes` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

From the man page of `logind.conf`,

> KillUserProcesses=
> Takes a boolean argument. Configures whether the processes of a user should be killed when the user logs out. If true, the scope
> unit corresponding to the session and all processes inside that scope
> will be terminated.

The solution is to explicitly start tmux in the user scope rather than in the session scope using the following.

```
systemd-run --scope --user tmux
```

Additionally, you need to enable "lingering" so that the tmux process can persist even if there is no active user session.

```
loginctl enable-linger
```

For more details, check the examples in the man page for [systemd-run](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html).

Answer (score 4):

While I don't remember if I've ever experienced the problem, I've been using a user service to have an "always-on" tmux server running anyway:

```
$ cat /home/tom/.config/systemd/user/tmux-server.service 
[Unit]
Description=tmux server

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -f %h/.config/tmux/server.conf start-server
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-server

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
$ cat /home/tom/.config/tmux/server.conf 
set -s exit-empty off
set -s exit-unattached off
```

and optionally:

```
set -g detach-on-destroy off
```

Certainly it requires lingering as well.